# Show linker error while integration of gmail in my app using swift

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7.3

I had followed this link to integrate gmail sign in in my project

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift#enable_sign-in

But it shows below linker error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_GSDK_NSClassFromString", referenced from:
      l010 in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
      l059 in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMOAuth2Authentication", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMOAuth2Keychain", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMOAuth2SignIn", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMSessionFetcher", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDRuntimeConfigFetcher.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMSessionFetcherService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_OpenInChromeController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Try `Clean`. Let the indexing happen and then `build` the project. See if this works.

Comment: i already tried this but not works @TheRohanSanap

Comment: @AmitKaushal Hi... Have you found any solution of this? Please guide me if you were successful in addressing this issue.

Comment: yes,I have solved issue by installing CocoaPods before that i used their SDK which gave above error .@Goti Follow this    https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating

Comment: @AmitKaushal Can you please join me in chat? I really want to solve this. Have been trying since 2 days.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766179/getting-clang-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invo/38261390#38261390