# Getting clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) while google signing

Tags: swift, google-signin

I'm getting this error while linking Google sign in without using cocoa pods.
I have referred many solutions here but none of them solved my issue. please guide me through a proper solution.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_GSDK_NSClassFromString", referenced from:
  l010 in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
  l059 in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMOAuth2Authentication", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
  objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMOAuth2Keychain", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMOAuth2SignIn", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
  objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMSessionFetcher", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
  objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDRuntimeConfigFetcher.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMSessionFetcherService", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_OpenInChromeController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 6):

> GoogleAppUtilities.framework
>    GoogleAuthUtilities.framework
>   GoogleNetworkingUtilities.framework
>   GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework
>   GoogleUtilities.framework
>   GoogleSignIn.framework
>    SystemConfiguration.framework
>   SafariServices.framework
>    AddressBook.framework
>   GoogleSignIn.bundle
>   libz.tbd

---

Add all framework in your project https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/  download Google Sign-In SDK 4.0.0

Comment: I have done already, but the issue has been resolved by old SDK < 4.0.0

Comment: Ok Always Welcome @DharmeshDhorajiya

Comment: =_= The google document is not correct. Just told us to import GoogleSignIn.framework
GoogleSignIn.bundle

Actually you have to import all of the frameworks inside the zip file

Answer (score 1):

Having the same error in integrating GIDSignin in my app , but resolved the error after installing it through cocoa pods.Try to install it through pods.

Answer (score 1):

**add all this from sdk(google_signin_sdk_4_0_0) to your project:**

```
GoogleAppUtilities.framework
GoogleAuthUtilities.framework
GoogleNetworkingUtilities.framework
GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework
GoogleUtilities.framework
GoogleSignIn.framework
GoogleSignIn.bundle
```

**Go to**

```
build Phases -> link binary with Libraries
```

**and add these frameworks:**

```
SafariServices.framework
AddressBook.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
```

**Also add this two files:**

```
libc++.tbd
libz.tbd
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you do cocoa pod using pod 'Google'? if so then do it using 'Google/SignIn'. Possibly you didn't do the appropriate import.